# How to identify an EC2 Classic Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Recently got an email titled, "Important News from AWS About Amazon EC2-Classic" describing some changes that need to occur. These emails from AWS usually reference the effected resources though and this one did not. I am having a hard time identifying what resources in our account are effected by this. All our EC2 instances are in a VPC and I am not even sure if anything needs to change or not.

**Is there a way to identify that an EC2 instance is classic?**

I have looked through their linked documentation and gone through the instances we have but I cannot tell if they are "classic" of not.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can identify the EC2-Classic env by checking the instance has VPC ID or not.

**EC2 console**

VPC ID is not shown by default. Enable VPC ID from `Preference` -> `Attribute columns`.

Then if VPC ID attribute is `-`, that means the instance is EC2-Classic. (Except that the instance state is not `terminated`.)

**CLI**

2 ways for checking. Output is none unless EC2-classic instances exist.

- Describe instance with EC2-Classic env.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters Name=instance-state-name,Values=pending,running,shutting-down,stopping,stopped | jq '.Reservations[].Instances[] | select(.VpcId == null)'
```

- Describe the instance if it is the EC2-Classic.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-id i-xxxxxxxxxxxx --filters Name=instance-state-name,Values=pending,running,shutting-down,stopping,stopped | jq '.Reservations[].Instances[] | select(.VpcId == null)'
```

***jq select for terminated state***

This is another way to filter the result of `aws ec2 describe-instances`.
Adding `.State.Name != "terminated" and` in jq select works the same as `--filters ...`. This might be more readable.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances | jq '.Reservations[].Instances[] | select(.State.Name != "terminated" and .VpcId == null)'
```

---

**Edit note:** Thanks to the suggestion from @AUdden, I have modified the CLI code for filtering out the `terminated` state. When we terminated instances (not stop), the instances exist for a while in terminated state. The terminated instances are not associated with VPC anymore. To do that, I have added `--filters Name=instance-state-name,Values=pending,running,shutting-down,stopping,stopped`.

Comment: oh man, thanks so much for your answer I was really struggling with this.  I do see a VPC ID value in the EC2 dashboard when looking at the instances.  Looking at the VPC it links to I also see that "classic link" is disabled, which I think I remember reading something about.  They are VPCs that we created so hopefully that is not an issue.

Comment: ClassicLink is used to connect EC2-Classic instances and VPC. So disabled is ok.

Comment: @shimo: Contributor AUdden identified [a potential edge case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70763643/3025856) that your solution doesn't address, but posted it as an answer since they don't have the reputation to comment. I wanted to draw your attention to it before it's deleted so you can determine if it makes sense to incorporate into your answer. They suggest modifying it to "filter out terminated instances", noting "It's an edge case but may lead folks with high turnover in accounts down a rabbit hole because EC2 instances that have been terminated are no longer associated with a VPC ID."

Comment: @JeremyCaney Thanks. I'd check that.

Comment: @shimo: Would it make sense to edit that into your answer? I ask because Stack Overflow isn't well-suited for answers that act as amendments to other answers, so AUdden's answer may get deleted.

Comment: @JeremyCaney : Yes. I have confirmed that the suggestion is right. My first code show unwanted results when EC2 instances with terminated state exist (for short time though). So I'd edit this.

Comment: Thanks for the CLI version - you can also add a loop to search all the regions you use:

```
for region in eu-west-1 eu-west-2 us-east-1 us-east-2; do aws ec2 describe-instances --region $region --filters Name=instance-state-name,Values=pending,running,shutting-down,stopping,stopped | jq '.Reservations[].Instances[] | select(.VpcId == null)'; done
```

Answer (score 3):

Amazon [provides a script](https://github.com/aws-samples/ec2-classic-resource-finder) to identify all resources affected by the retirement, including resources you may not consider such as security groups.

Important: Check the file *errors.txt* after running the script. The script will happily run through its steps even if there is an error (such as missing/wrong credentials) without showing any hint of trouble in the console output.